# Creating a dictionary from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

From this list of tuples:

```
[('IND', 'MIA', '05/30'), ('ND', '07/30'), ('UNA', 'ONA', '100'), \
('LAA', 'SUN', '05/30'), ('AA', 'SN', '07/29'), ('UAA', 'AAN')]
```

I want to create a dictionary, which keys will be `[0]` and `[1]` value of **every third tuple**. Thus, the first key of dict created should be `'IND, MIA'`, second key `'LAA, SUN'`

The final result should be:

```
{'IND, MIA': [('IND', 'MIA', '05/30'), ('ND', '07/30'), ('UNA', 'ONA', '100')],\
'LAA, SUN': [('LAA', 'SUN', '05/30'), ('AA', 'SN', '07/29'), ('UAA', 'AAN')]}
```

If this is of any relevance, once the values in question becomes keys, they may be removed from tuple, since then I do not need them anymore. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not use tuples as keys instead of strings? ('IND','MIA') instead of 'IND, MIA' for example. Seems more elegant, and allows for commas inside of your keys without obfuscating the keys.

Comment: what do you want to happen if the number of items is not evenly divisible by 3 (compare @J0HN's answer that has no padding and Martijn's one with izip_longest())?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
inp = [('IND', 'MIA', '05/30'), ('ND', '07/30'), ('UNA', 'ONA', '100'), \
       ('LAA', 'SUN', '05/30'), ('AA', 'SN', '07/29'), ('UAA', 'AAN')]

result = {}
for i in range(0, len(inp), 3):
    item = inp[i]
    result[item[0]+","+item[1]] = inp[i:i+3]

print (result)
```

Dict comprehension solution is possible, but somewhat messy.

To remove keys from array replace second loop line (`result[item[0]+ ...`) with

```
result[item[0]+","+item[1]] = [item[2:]]+inp[i+1:i+3]
```

Dict comprehension solution (a bit less messy than I initially thought :))

```
rslt = {
    inp[i][0]+", "+inp[i][1]: inp[i:i+3]
    for i in range(0, len(inp), 3)
}
```

And to add more kosher stuff into the answer, here's some useful links :): [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects), [dict comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Comment: you don't need `defaultdict` here, an ordinary `dict` will do.

Comment: Thanks you! I pick the dict comprehension solution for most concise way.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yes, you're right, leftover of first version that used list append to collect those elements. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`itertools` `grouper` recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

{', '.join(g[0][:2]): g for g in grouper(inputlist, 3)}
```

should do it.

The `grouper()` method gives us groups of 3 tuples at a time.

Removing the key values from the dictionary values too:

```
{', '.join(g[0][:2]): (g[0][2:],) + g[1:]  for g in grouper(inputlist, 3)}
```

Demo on your input:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint({', '.join(g[0][:2]): g for g in grouper(inputlist, 3)})
{'IND, MIA': (('IND', 'MIA', '05/30'), ('ND', '07/30'), ('UNA', 'ONA', '100')),
 'LAA, SUN': (('LAA', 'SUN', '05/30'), ('AA', 'SN', '07/29'), ('UAA', 'AAN'))}
>>> pprint({', '.join(g[0][:2]): (g[0][2:],) + g[1:]  for g in grouper(inputlist, 3)})
{'IND, MIA': (('05/30',), ('ND', '07/30'), ('UNA', 'ONA', '100')),
 'LAA, SUN': (('05/30',), ('AA', 'SN', '07/29'), ('UAA', 'AAN'))}
```

Comment: As always much obliged! I wish I could use accept button twice here. THX.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def solve(lis, skip = 0):
    dic = defaultdict(list)
    it = iter(lis)                    # create an iterator
    for elem in it:
        key = ", ".join(elem[:2])     # create key
        dic[key].append(elem)
        for elem in xrange(skip):     # append the next two items to the 
            dic[key].append(next(it)) # dic as skip =2 
    print dic


solve([('IND', 'MIA', '05/30'), ('ND', '07/30'), ('UNA', 'ONA', '100'), \
('LAA', 'SUN', '05/30'), ('AA', 'SN', '07/29'), ('UAA', 'AAN')], skip = 2)
```

**output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>,
 {'LAA, SUN': [('LAA', 'SUN', '05/30'), ('AA', 'SN', '07/29'), ('UAA', 'AAN')],
 'IND, MIA': [('IND', 'MIA', '05/30'), ('ND', '07/30'), ('UNA', 'ONA', '100')]
 })
```